# Android ADT Eclipse plugin, parseSDKContent failed

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I've just set up my first Android development environment consisting of

- Eclipse 3.5
- Mac OSX 10.5
- Android SDK for x86 macs
- ADT Eclipse plugin 0.9.6

I've set set $PATH to my SDK/tools directory (which shouldn't matter if I only use Eclipse right?) and started Eclipse, but when I try to set the path to the SDK in Eclipse, i get the error "parseSdkContent failed". The stack trace of from the thrown exception is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newInstance(SchemaFactory.java:181)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.LayoutDevicesXsd.getValidator(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.LayoutDeviceManager.parseLayoutDevices(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.LayoutDeviceManager.loadDefaultLayoutDevices(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.LayoutDeviceManager.loadDefaultAndUserDevices(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.Sdk.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.Sdk.loadSdk(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AdtPlugin$13.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

I can't see that I've missed anything in the setup process, according to the instructions it should basically just work out of the box. Any ideas as to why this might fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick glance at http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/SchemaFactory.html suggests that something is wrong with the JDK 1.6 setup.

Setting the -vm flag in eclipse to the original 1.5 did not help, but after removing all traces of the apparently misconfigured 1.6 everything worked like a charm.

Comment: can you elaborate the answer?

Comment: I would if I could but I'm afraid there is no way I can remember the details. But interpreting my own answer suggests that something was wrong with my JDK installation and completely removing it and reinstalling solved the issue.

Answer (score 7):

So my solution was completely different.  The project.properties was corrupted.  I had to edit it from the command line as eclipse didn't want to do anything for me.  I deleted everything that was unnecessary.  So that the file looked like this:

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system use,
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.

# Project target.
target=android-15
```

Closed Eclipse.  Opened it again.

I then went back into the project properties and reset my libraries.  This solved the problem.  Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Eclipse change each backslash (\) into a double backslash (\\) in the library paths. A find & replace all did the trick

Answer (score 7):

For me updating the DDMS from ADT plugin did the trick!

Before that for saving time I only updated **ADT plugin**, nothing else like Android DDMS, TraceView etc. so I ran into same issue, after couple of restarts and Google searches everyone was proposing different solutions. I updated my **Android DDMS** and restarted eclipse.

***And It worked like a charm.***

I didn't had to remove my workspace or update my .project file etc.

Answer (score 3):

Step 1. Find the folder named: .android

This folder can be located in your Windows user directory, for example in Windows 8: 
C:\Users\YOUR_WINDOWS_USERNAME.android
Step 2. Delete this folder .android

Step 3. Restart Eclipse and it is OK now

Answer (score 0):

I try removeing all your projects then restart the application

Answer (score 0):

- Installed API 19
- Deinstalled API 20, 20L

Under Package Explorer|appcompat_v7  Android 4.4.2 didn't show up

Then removed corresponding 20-and 20L-folders in sdk/platforms and sdk/system-images

Restart and ok

ADT Package 23.0.2.1259578
Eclipse Platform 4.2.2.M20130204-1200

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7 with `adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702`:
removing 
`C:\Users\YOUR_WINDOWS_USERNAME.android`
 did the magic for me :)