# Android XML validation using XSD ( both xerces and SchemaFactory) error

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, xsd, xerces

Now, I'm having some pb with XML validation using XSD.

Since I use SchemaFactory:

```
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
```

It give me:

```
Exception Ljava/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError; thrown while initializing Lorg/apache/xerces/impl/xs/SchemaGrammar;
Exception Ljava/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError; thrown while initializing Lorg/apache/xerces/impl/xs/XSConstraints;
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
```

Then I tried to switch to apache xerces and got this error (since importing xerces):

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I found these topics but they didn't help me:

[Validator (xsd) for xml in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596540/validator-xsd-for-xml-in-android)

[xml schema conversion issue against xsd giving Illeagal exception in android applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385914/xml-schema-conversion-issue-against-xsd-giving-illeagal-exception-in-android-app)

[SchemaFactory doesn't support W3C XML Schema in platform level 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129934/schemafactory-doesnt-support-w3c-xml-schema-in-platform-level-8)

[why java.exe exit with value 1 in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957412/why-java-exe-exit-with-value-1-in-android-studio)

I'm using Android Studio 1.2.2 and an Android 4.4.2.
Any suggestion for me? Thanks,

Comment: I just tried jdk 1.7 but I still can't pass "java.exe finished..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: xerces for android: https://code.google.com/p/xerces-for-android/source/checkout