# SchemaFactory.newInstance() exception

Tags: android, xml-parsing, xsd, sax, xml-validation

I am trying to check an xml against an schema for Android, but in the first very line of the function, when creating the **schema factory instance**, I get an exception.

Exception line:

> schemaFactory= SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

I have also used [XMLSchema-instance](http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance) and [XMLSchema](http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema), but got the same exception at the beginning.

I have seen that many other people are having the same issue, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129934/schemafactory-doesnt-support-w3c-xml-schema-in-platform-level-8), but I haven't found the answer to this problem yet.

FYI - I am using it in the following function:

```
public static boolean validateWithExtXSDUsingSAX(String xml, String xsd) throws
        ParserConfigurationException, IOException {
    try {
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setValidating(false);
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

        SchemaFactory schemaFactory = null;
        try {
            schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("schema factory error" + e.getMessage());
        }

        SAXParser parser = null;

        try {
            factory.setSchema(schemaFactory.newSchema(new Source[] { new StreamSource(xsd) }));
            parser = factory.newSAXParser();
        } catch (SAXException se) {
            System.out.println("SCHEMA : " + se.getMessage()); // problem in
                                                               // the XSD
                                                               // itself
            return false;
        }

        XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();
        reader.setErrorHandler(

        new ErrorHandler() {

            public void warning(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
                System.out.println("WARNING: " + e.getMessage()); // do
                                                                  // nothing
            }

            public void error(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
                System.out.println("ERROR : " + e.getMessage());
                throw e;
            }

            public void fatalError(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
                System.out.println("FATAL : " + e.getMessage());
                throw e;
            }
        });

        reader.parse(new InputSource(xml));

        return true;
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        throw pce;
    } catch (IOException io) {
        throw io;
    } catch (SAXException se) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

There are some issues with the Java XML validator included in the original versions of Android. You can try to use Xerces instead, you can download it form here:

http://code.google.com/p/xerces-for-android/

Although there are no downloads in the downloads section, you can do an SVN checkout to download the source code.

Comment: @tommyk check my new edit, let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and found lots of similar questions out there, but no good examples on how to do it. The following is what I did with Xerces-for-Android to get my stuff to work. Good luck :)

The following worked for me:

1. Create a validation utility.
2. Get both the xml and xsd into file on the android OS and use the validation utility against it.
3. Use Xerces-For-Android to do the validation.

Android does support some packages which we can use, I created my xml validation utility based on: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/package-summary.html

My initial sandbox testing was pretty smooth with java, then I tried to port it over to Dalvik and found that my code did not work. Some things just aren't supported the same with Dalvik, so I made some modifications.

I found a reference to xerces for android, so I modified my sandbox test of (**the following doesn't work with android, the example after this does**):

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.Validator;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;

/**
 * A Utility to help with xml communication validation.
 */
public class XmlUtil {

    /**
     * Validation method. 
     * Base code/example from: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/package-summary.html
     * 
     * @param xmlFilePath The xml file we are trying to validate.
     * @param xmlSchemaFilePath The schema file we are using for the validation. This method assumes the schema file is valid.
     * @return True if valid, false if not valid or bad parse. 
     */
    public static boolean validate(String xmlFilePath, String xmlSchemaFilePath) {

        // parse an XML document into a DOM tree
        DocumentBuilder parser = null;
        Document document;

        // Try the validation, we assume that if there are any issues with the validation
        // process that the input is invalid.
        try {
            // validate the DOM tree
            parser = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            document = parser.parse(new File(xmlFilePath));

            // create a SchemaFactory capable of understanding WXS schemas
            SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

            // load a WXS schema, represented by a Schema instance
            Source schemaFile = new StreamSource(new File(xmlSchemaFilePath));
            Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);

            // create a Validator instance, which can be used to validate an instance document
            Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
            validator.validate(new DOMSource(document));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Catches: SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, and IOException.
            return false;
        }     

        return true;
    }
}
```

The above code had to be modified some to work with xerces for android (http://gc.codehum.com/p/xerces-for-android/). You need SVN to get the project, the following are some crib notes:

```
download xerces-for-android
    download silk svn (for windows users) from http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download
        install silk svn (I did complete install)
        Once the install is complete, you should have svn in your system path.
        Test by typing "svn" from the command line.
        I went to my desktop then downloaded the xerces project by:
            svn checkout http://xerces-for-android.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ xerces-for-android-read-only
        You should then have a new folder on your desktop called xerces-for-android-read-only
```

With the above jar (Eventually I'll make it into a jar, just copied it directly into my source for quick testing. If you wish to do the same, you can making the jar quickly with Ant (http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html)), I was able to get the following to work for my xml validation:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import mf.javax.xml.transform.Source;
import mf.javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import mf.javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import mf.javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import mf.javax.xml.validation.Validator;
import mf.org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

/**
 * A Utility to help with xml communication validation.
 */public class XmlUtil {

    /**
     * Validation method. 
     * 
     * @param xmlFilePath The xml file we are trying to validate.
     * @param xmlSchemaFilePath The schema file we are using for the validation. This method assumes the schema file is valid.
     * @return True if valid, false if not valid or bad parse or exception/error during parse. 
     */
    public static boolean validate(String xmlFilePath, String xmlSchemaFilePath) {

        // Try the validation, we assume that if there are any issues with the validation
        // process that the input is invalid.
        try {
            SchemaFactory  factory = new XMLSchemaFactory();
            Source schemaFile = new StreamSource(new File(xmlSchemaFilePath));
            Source xmlSource = new StreamSource(new File(xmlFilePath));
            Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);
            Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
            validator.validate(xmlSource);
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Catches everything beyond: SAXException, and IOException.
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (Error e) {
            // Needed this for debugging when I was having issues with my 1st set of code.
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

**Some Side Notes:**

For creating the files, I made a simple file utility to write string to files:

```
public static void createFileFromString(String fileText, String fileName) {
    try {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        output.write(fileText);
        output.close();
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I also needed to write to an area that I had access to, so I made use of:

```
String path = this.getActivity().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).applicationInfo.dataDir;
```

A little hackish, it works. I'm sure there is a more succinct way of doing this, however I figured I'd share my success, as there weren't any good examples that I found.

Comment: Hi, I am writing Junit for a method which internally calls a responsevalidator method which has the 2 lines of code SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
  Schema schema = sf.newSchema(object.getClass().getResource("/schema/" + xsdName));...it is throwing null in the 2nd line...how can i mock or set some value so that it does not throw null in junit

Answer (score 0):

Link for download jar file [xerces-for-android.jar](https://xerces-for-android.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=10001000&name=xerces-for-android.jar&token=ABZ6GAc7O-z2sUWIxY-w5VwRzPTAD6yFww%3A1419578867304) from google repository.

If above link is unavailable, use this page for downloading: [xerces](https://code.google.com/p/xerces-for-android/issues/detail?id=1)